# Why is Azure SQL query hanging my app?

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm writing up my first app that makes use of the Azure mobile services platform. I have a SQL server configured and the table is showing up on the Azure management portal. I have manually added some entries to the table to ensure nothing is wrong on the server-side.

My problems lie in the fact that my app hangs when I perform a query on the table. Here's my code:

```
public MUManager(Context con){
    context = con;
    try {
        Log.i("Counter", "Before mClient");
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://blah.com","apikey",context);
        Log.i("Counter", "After mClient");
        muTable = mClient.getTable("table1",MUItem.class);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.i("Counter", "MalformedURL");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Counter", "End of constructor");

}
```

Now, I'm not having any issues with the above code, but I also have no way of confirming that the client is actually connecting to the Azure Mobile Service.

Below is the code which causes my issue.

```
public ArrayList<MU> getMUList() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Log.i("Counter", "Start SQL");
    MobileServiceList<MUItem> resultList = muTable.where().field("fieldname").eq("fieldvalue").execute().get();

    Log.i("Counter", "SQL success!");
    ArrayList<MU> MUList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.i("Counter", "MU Initialization successful!");
    for(MUItem m:resultList){
        Log.i("Counter", m.Name);
        MUList.add(getMUfromItem(m));
    }
    return MUList;
}
```

The above code freezes when I arrive at the line:

```
    MobileServiceList<MUItem> resultList = muTable.where().field("fieldname").eq("fieldvalue").execute().get();
```

I receive no errors, but I never see my SQL Success! statement appear in the logs and the app freezes as if there were an IO block or something.

I have all the necessary Gradle dependencies I think, here they are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
```

Very confused, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've just had a play and found that its the get() function causing the code to hang. I don't know why, but even when the command is issued on a insert order, it seems to cause the hang. I'm reading into why get() causes the hang but I'm struggling to find anything of value

EDIT 2:
So I just connected my phone, a physical android device to see if the same error would occur on a physical as it has been in the emulator. I now get a slightly more verbose output, instead of the app just hanging I receive the following:

```
    getaddrinfo+,hn 30(0x736565722d696e),sn(),family 0,flags 4
    getaddrinfo-,err=8
    getaddrinfo+,hn 30(0x736565722d696e),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
    getaddrinfo-, 1
    getaddrinfo_proxy+
    getaddrinfo_proxy-,TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY
```

It then proceeds to hang after that. Any ideas what this means?

Comment: You are probably timing out on the connect. Why can't you get a confirmation of a valid connection?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how I can confirm that I have a connection without querying a table. As I've said, I'm new to Azure so if there is a way I would love to hear it.

Comment: You should add a catch with no expression a blank catch(), for all other traffic. Perhaps, connection exception is coming in unexpected.

Comment: A blank catch? I get a syntax error inserting a blank catch.

Comment: While trouble shooting add a catch(Exception e){ log(e.ErrorMessage);}

Comment: I have added a catch with a printStackTrace statement, however there are no error messages coming out. I have confirmed now that the MobileServiceClient is connecting to Azure, its just the get() operation causing the hang. It's as if any interaction with the table, including insert() or execute() takes an unlimited amount of time to complete...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem, slightly embarrassing actually!
The problem was that my permissions clause asking for Internet access was inside of the  clause!